# How to serialize a collection (with an indexer property) as a dictionary

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class, `FooCollection` let's say, which implements `IEnumerable<Foo>`, and also provides an indexer by which one can look up a `Foo` by its name. Functionally it's read-only as a dictionary. But it's not really a dictionary because users do not get to decide on the keys.

Anyway, I want JSON.NET to serialize this object as a JSON dictionary, instead of as an array, which it's doing now. Sticking `JsonDictionaryAttribute` on it doesn't work: then it does nothing.

Clues?

Comment: Why don't you post your code instead of describing the process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably going to need to create a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for your `FooCollection` class in order to serialize it the way you want.  Since you haven't posted any code at all, I'll just make something up for sake of example. Let's say your `Foo` and `FooCollection` classes look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class FooCollection : IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    private List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

    public void Add(Foo foo)
    {
        list.Add(foo);
    }

    public Foo this[string name]
    {
        get { return list.Find(f => f.Name == name); }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)list).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The following converter would serialize the `FooCollection` as if it were a dictionary.  I'm assuming that you would want the converter to use the value of the `Name` property as the key for each `Foo` for purposes of serialization (to match the indexer on the collection), so that is how I implemented it.  You can change it to something else by modifying the `GetFooKey()` method.

```
class FooCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(FooCollection));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (Foo foo in (FooCollection)value)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(GetFooKey(foo));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    // Given a Foo, return its unique key to be used during serialization
    private string GetFooKey(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo.Name;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is an example program that demonstrates how to use the converter.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FooCollection coll = new FooCollection();
        coll.Add(new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Moe" });
        coll.Add(new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "Larry" });
        coll.Add(new Foo { Id = 3, Name = "Curly" });

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new FooCollectionConverter());
        settings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(coll, settings);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

And here is the output of the above program:

```
{
  "Moe": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Moe"
  },
  "Larry": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Larry"
  },
  "Curly": {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Curly"
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wI2iQG

Comment: Could you share the example for ReadJson method?