# How to parse a list of the same object to JSON in different name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an object `Person` like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to create a list like this:

```
 var personList = new List<object>();
 personList.Add(new Person { Address = "addr1", Age = 20, Name = "Person1" });
 personList.Add(new Person { Address = "addr2", Age = 22, Name = "Person2" });
 personList.Add(new Person { Address = "addr3", Age = 25, Name = "Person1" });

 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personList);
```

This is the result of `jsonString`

```
[{"Name":"Person1","Age":20,"Address":"addr1"},

{"Name":"Person2","Age":22,"Address":"addr2"},

{"Name":"Person1","Age":25,"Address":"addr3"}]
```

Below is my expected result, so how can I do that?

```
{
    Person1:{"Name":"Person1","Age":20,"Address":"addr1"},

    Person2:{"Name":"Person2","Age":22,"Address":"addr2"},

    Person3:{"Name":"Person3","Age":25,"Address":"addr3"}
}
```

Comment: You wont get Person1, Person2, types unless you have individual properties for those. Are there always going to be 3 person objects? I'm assuming the list is dynamic

Comment: Ya, this list is dynamic and it will have more than 3 people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `Dictionary<string, Person>` when I am not that wrong.
This should serialize it that way, you want it.

You can add the Attribute `[JsonIgnore]` to `Name` optionally, if you don't want redundant data.

**Edit:** You can serialize a list directly to a dictionary by using a custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm): [Newtonsoft.Json serialize collection (with indexer) as dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579427/newtonsoft-json-serialize-collection-with-indexer-as-dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    // constructor
    public Person(string name, int age, string address){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.Address = address;
    }
 }
```

then

```
 List<person>People = new List<person>();
 People.Add(new Person("name1", 1, "address1"));
 People.Add(new Person("name2", 2, "address2"));
 People.Add(new Person("name3", 3, "address3"));


string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(People);
```

then on the client, omitting the part about getting it to the client

```
var people = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

Comment: You are answering to the question. That way you can serialize, but the resulted json string is the same as the topic writer is getting falsely.